# jQuery(document).bind not working in Opera

Tags: jquery, callback, bind, opera

I am having issues with the bind function in Opera.

**Case:**

jQuery: v1.8
Opera: v12.13   Build: 1734
OS: Windows 7 64bit

I am binding the document to monitor changes in DOM Subtree.

```
jQuery(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
    console.log("DOMSubtreeModified");
});
```

Working fine on Chrome/FireFox/IE8+. But in Opera the callback is never triggered. I have been looking in the forums but did not see any reported issue. Any insight as to why this might be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not supported by Opera:

http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=154019 and 
http://help.dottoro.com/ljrmcldi.php

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom) you may find some info about how to check if DOM is modified without that event.

Comment: I have been to that link earlier and seeing the authoring date of Aug, 2006 I thought that it might be fixed by now. But the SO link was very helpful. I think I will go with that. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps I should add that listening for DOM mutation events may harm performance and the relevant W3C working groups are trying to find a better way to do this and deprecate DOM mutation events for this reason - it's hard or impossible to make a good and performant implementation.